# Check URL for paramter and copy into input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check the URL for a parameter. If this parameter exists, I want to pass it into an input.

The URL is eg. www.xyz.com/?userid=1234

The goal should be:

1. Check if URL contains parameter "userid="
2. If yes, set the value as input of a value

My problem is, that I don't know, how to grab the value of the parameter. In my opinion it must be something like "take everything after "userid=" up to the end or an "&" (as possible beginn of new value)".

I think I would do with:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userid" type="text" value="" />
```

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('userid=') > -1) { ... }
$('input[name=userid]').val('...');
```

In the end, the input should be have the value "1234" in my example.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21903119/783014). It should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) interface to grab the query string value using [`searchParams.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get).

```
var params = new URLSearchParams(url);
console.log(params.get("userid"));
```

To check if a search parameter exists in the URL, use [`URLSearchParams.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/has)

```
params.has('userid') === true;
```

Comment: Thank you! I found the full solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930667/trying-to-pass-url-parameters-to-input-fields-not-form-fields